# Decrement variables that contain letters

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed

I have a set of valid characters [0-9a-zA-Z] and a variable that is assigned one of these characters. What I want to do is to be able to decrement that variable to the next in the set.

I can't figure out how to decrement letters , it works for numbers only.

```
#!/bin/bash
test=b
echo $test  # this shows 'b'
let test-=1
echo $test  # I want it to be 'a'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of

```
test=$(tr 1-9a-zA-Z 0-9a-zA-Y <<<"$test")
```

is that it correctly (I think) decrements `a` to `9` and `A` to `z`. And if that is not the order you want, it is easy to adjust.

See  [man tr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html)  for details. This is the Gnu version of `tr`; character ranges are not guaranteed by Posix, but most `tr` implementations have them. `<<<` "here strings" are also a common extension, which bash implements.

Comment: this will translate `ba` to `a9`

Comment: @sundeep, yes, and it will leave `$` unmodified. OP says he has a variable which "contains *one* of these characters" so I think I have answered tbe question which was asked. ( I have a similar answer for the string  ase, so feel free to ask a different question.

Answer (score 0):

```
test=$(printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$(($(printf '%d' "'$test") - 1 ))")")
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. If the value of test starts with `A` the result will be `@`

Comment: While these commands may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how they answer the question. Please [include an explanation for your commands](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For command-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) [The same goes for incorrect answers.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

test=b

if [[ $test == A || $test == a || $test == 0 ]]
then
    echo "character already at lowest value"
else
    # convert $test to decimal digit
    test_digit=$(printf '%d' "'$test")

    decremented=$(( test_digit - 1 ))

    # print $decremented as a char
    printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$decremented")\n"
fi
```

reference:
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071

Comment: No, this will reduce the ascii value of `A` (for example) to the ascii value of `@`, which is not in the list supplied: `0-9a-zA-Z`.

Answer (score 0):

If we set a variable (say `a`) to the whole string of characters:

```
$ a=$( IFS=''; set -- {0..9} {a..z} {A..Z}; echo "$*"); echo "$a"
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

We may take advantage of the fact that bash "arithmetic" may use a base up to 62 (in the same order as the letters presented).

```
$ test="A"; echo "${a:$((62#$test-1)):1}"
z
```

This works only for "one character" (and not zero 0).

It may be expanded to several characters, but that is not being asked.